# Vote to delete [unnamed] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [unnamed](/questions/tagged/unnamed) tag seems like a useless tag. Unnamed what?

I was thinking of writing a wiki but what will it be?

There are 13 questions with that tag, all of which have other, better tags describing them. The content ranges from unnamed variables, to classes, to git repositories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are all gone now.

[image: Happy pandas]

Comment: That was quick ;-). I trashed the last one about 5 seconds before you posted this! (Someone else got the other 12).

Comment: @Ben it was the pandas O.O